# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to read files

Tags: java, file, stream

hi
i have a little program here that gets a directory from the command line and adds all the files in this directory and its sub-folders.. so here's the code:

```
package oop.ex1.filescript;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyFileScript {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File dir = new File(args[0]);
    //LINE 13
    ArrayList<File> files = readAllFiles(dir.listFiles());

}

private static ArrayList<File> readAllFiles(File[] dir){

    ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
            //LINE 28
    for(File itr : dir) {
        result.add(itr); 
        if (!itr.isFile()) {
            File[] temp = itr.listFiles();
                            //LINE 32
            ArrayList<File> deeperList = readAllFiles(temp);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;

}
```

}

now when i run it on certain folders with not many files in them everything is okay, but when i feed it folders with a lot of files i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at oop.ex1.filescript.MyFileScript.readAllFiles(MyFileScript.java:28)
at oop.ex1.filescript.MyFileScript.readAllFiles(MyFileScript.java:32)
at oop.ex1.filescript.MyFileScript.readAllFiles(MyFileScript.java:32)
at oop.ex1.filescript.MyFileScript.main(MyFileScript.java:13)
```

any idea as for why it happens? thanks!
p.s. i marked line numbers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write it this way.  Works fine when I test it:

```
public static List<File> getAllChildFiles(File[] dir)
{

    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File file : dir)
    {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] children = file.listFiles();
            List<File> grandChildren = getAllChildFiles(children);
            result.addAll(grandChildren);
        }
        else
        {
            result.add(file);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: hi, what advantage does list has over ArrayList?

Comment: Design to interfaces - never heard of the idea?  You don't advertise the concrete type of the class, so if you change it clients aren't affected.  Look at the java.sql package - all the important classes are interfaces.  Ever think about why?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like dir.listFiles returned null.

Quoting the doc, "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.".

Answer (score 2):

The `dir` variable in line 28 is probably null. You might want to include a check on the result of `dir.listFiles()` before calling `readAllFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (!itr.isFile()) {
```

use

```
if (itr.isDirectory()) {
```

If it is not a file it is not neccesarily a directory.

Comment: nice to know/ what else can it be?

Comment: @yotamoo Device drivers, named pipes etc. etc. - But even if this wasn't true, when you want to test if something is a directory why not just use `isDirectory()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do `if (itr.isDirectory())` and check for null `if (tmp != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `listFile(FileFilter)` and have your `FileFilter` return `File.canRead()`. See if you get all expected files and if not figure out why they aren't readable.